# navbar não carrega adequadamente

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-4

Estou estudando HTML e decidi adicionar o *Bootstrap 4* em um pequeno projeto. Ao navegar na listagem de componentes no site do *Bootstrap* me deparei com o seguinte `navbar`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </nav>
```

Após baixar e referenciar o *framework* na página `index.html` notei que o *navbar* não funciona adequadamente quando a tela está reduzida e o botão *toggle* está sendo exibido. Então pensei que fosse algum problema com o *Bootstrap* pois  visualizei o seguinte erro ao abrir o console do navegador:

[image: Erro console]

Novamente eu mudei o *Bootstrap* e o *jQuery* para versão *.min* e mesmo assim o erro persistiu. Curiosamente pude observar que no navegador *Edge* o erro persiste, entretanto se eu usar um interpretador online de *HTML*, essa falha não ocorre e o botão *toggle* funciona normalmente exibindo os itens ocultos.

O que devo fazer para solucionar?

Comment: Cara muito provavelmente a ordenação dos scripts no seu documento está errada. Pois eu teste esse código da NavBar aqui e não acusa erro algum no console tanto no Chrome quanto no Edge. Coloque o seu documento inteiro ai na pergunta que fica mais fácil pra te dar uma resposta precisa.

Comment: Vc deve carregar o `jquery.js` antes do `bootstrap.js`.

Comment: Sam, funcionou... coloca como resposta para a pergunta...